# Versioning Nuget Package with GitVersion.yml in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I'm stucking with this for a whole week and I didn't reach where i wanted. 
I'm thinking about having two branches:

-**master**

-**release**(we are calling it **vNext** - the whole company knows it by this name)

Master branch will generate the packages without prerelease tag.
Release will generate the pre release version like:

=>**master** is on 1.0.0

=>Create a **vNext**(release) branch like: **vNext/1.1.0**

=> Code things needed here and commit;

=> Automatically my pipeline is triggered, because I've set the trigger to branch **master**, **vNext** or **vNext/***

=> I want this to create a package like  (1.1.0-beta1)

=>Create a pullRequest to **master**

=> Automatically my pipeline is triggered,

=> I want this to create a package like  (1.1.0)

This is my gitVersion.yml

```
next-version: 1.0
mode: Mainline
legacy-semver-padding: 0
build-metadata-padding: 0
commits-since-version-source-padding: 0
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
assembly-informational-format: '{LegacySemVer}'
branches:
  master:
    regex: master
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    tag: ''
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  release:
    regex: vNext?[/-]
    source-branches: ['master']
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    tag: beta
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch:  true
```

I can't get this working fine. To reach where I'm now, I've already googled a lot even here in stackoverflow, but couldn't found a solution that fits in the scenario I need.

[image: Builds]
[image: vNext 1.1.1-beta1]
[image: Merge to Master]

Also https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cy-K3P4ajyUUvvtdt0oa5_NTp1FZ-UIF

This are the logs from builds

Answer (score 2):

As my test, I change your yml as below.

```
next-version: 1.0
mode: Mainline
legacy-semver-padding: 0
build-metadata-padding: 0
commits-since-version-source-padding: 0
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
assembly-informational-format: '{LegacySemVer}'
branches:
  master:
    regex: master
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    tag: ''
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  release:
    regex: vNext
    source-branches: ['master']
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    tag: beta
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch:  true
```

Then I get the result as this.
[image]

Hope this will help.